# How to copy database file to sdcard in android

Tags: android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup database file to sdcard on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android)

I'm working on phonegap 1.3.0. I've created database named test.db in phonegap which is stored in data/data/(pakage name)/test.db. I'm using native android code to copy the database to sdcard (mnt/sdcard). But it is giving error that test.db is not present. The device is not rooted. What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Code is as follows->

```
public void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String DBPATH = "/data/data/package_name/databases/";
     String DBNAME = "test.db";
     String myPath = DBPATH + DBNAME;

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(myPath);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/folder/test.db";

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput;
    try {
    myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The phonegap code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
function createDB() {
    db.transaction(populateDB);
}
function populateDB(tx) {
    Field17=document.form.Field17.value;
    Field18=document.form.Field18.value;
    Field19=document.form.Field19.value;
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INFO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INFO (pid integer primary key, field17,field18,field19');
    sql = "INSERT INTO INFO (field17,field18,field19) VALUES ( '" + Field17 + "','" + Field18 + "','" + Field19 + "')";
    tx.executeSql(sql);
    db.transaction(queryDB);
}


function queryDB(tx,results) {
    console.log("inside querydb");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM INFO', [], querySuccess);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {     
var len = results.rows.length;
    alert('rows inserted: ' + len);
    if (len > 0) {
        for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

            console.log('pid: ' + results.rows.item(i).pid + 'field: ' + results.rows.item(i).field17 + ' field: ' + results.rows.item(i).field18+ ' field ' + results.rows.item(i).field19);

        }
    }
}       


</script>
```

Comment: **new FileInputStream("myPath");** Is this line correct? or it should be **new FileInputStream(myPath);**

Comment: Yeah right! sorry for mistake.. I have corrected it but still code is not working. I tried moving file from /mnt/sdcard to /mnt/sdcard/folder. It is working fine. But when I tried /data/data/pkg_name/databases/test.db to /mnt/sdcard/folder/test.db, it is not working.

Comment: Hi Please check code at dis link may be useful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814213/making-a-database-backup-to-sdcard-on-android

Answer (score 1):

you no need to root your phone. Check permission
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` .

you can check file

```
File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        if(dbFile.exists()){
                  //Continue
```

Edit: test this code. Change your pakage name and yourFoler in sdcard

```
public boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

public void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    private static String DB_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.app.android.dictionary/databases/";
if(checkDataBase()){
InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/foler/" + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput;
    try {
    myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest. But it is not going in if(dbFile.exists()) condition. I'm getting error as test.db is not present.

Comment: I tried the above code but checkDataBase() function is returning "false".

Comment: Do you debug on Emulator or real phone?. You can use DDMS of Eclispe to check file test.db exists. File Explorer of DDMS check the path data/data/com.sun.(pakage name).../databases/ SQLite db file

Comment: No I'm using HTC wildfire S for testing.

Comment: i think your file doesn't exists. Check your file with USB debugging with DDMS. you can push or pull file from devices

Comment: Ok. But before running this code, I'm running my phonegap application so database should exists in data/data/pkgname/databases/ right?

Comment: so. Your phonegap application can't create database and store in data/data/pkg/database. Can you post phonegap app code?. I test successfull with ss galaxy s captivate. Rom Stock 2.1 & not root

Comment: I've added the Phonegap code in my question.

Comment: :). The error is path of db source file. Db file store in /data/data/pkg name/app_database/Database.db . The name of database is always Database.db. :). it is main database contains information of your database including sub folder and your database filename. Example: sub folder is file__0 and file name is 0000000000000001.db. (Sorry about my English grammar not good. :D)

Comment: Thanks! I tried using data/data/pkgname/Database.db as a path which should result into moving Database.db file to sdcard but it is not working. Also I tried data/data/pkgname/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db which is also not working. :(

Comment: check location of your create file. are you sure that file already exists?. You can push a db file example to test. And the location of me is /data/data/pkg name/app_database/Database.db.

Comment: From eclipse->DDMS->File explorer, I've seen the path. I couldn't push a database file to device as I don't have root permissions. Is there any other way to check whether the database file exists in the device or not?

Comment: why? i could push a database file to my device. Trying to up rom your device.no needed to root. (You can root and test with root explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Application doesn't create the database, actually it is created by Android system and the file permission of the database is **-rw-rw----**. It means only the User and the group can access it and in this case both are **system**. So your program doesn't have right to access, hence you got the "Permission Denied" error.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So to get the permission do I need to root the device?