# Run a class onClick() in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, database

I would like to export my database to my sdcard. I am trying to follow this question:
[Making a database backup to SDCard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814213/making-a-database-backup-to-sdcard-on-android)

But since I'm still pretty new to programming, I'm not sure If I'm doing this right. I made a separate class for `ExportDatabaseFileTask.java` so now I just have to call it in my main.

In my main I have an onClick listener that executes this code:

```
        ExportDatabaseFileTask thing = new ExportDatabaseFileTask();
```

Is that line enough to run the code in my class to export the database?

Comment: Depends on the code you did put in ExportDatabaseFileTask....

Comment: I believe I put in the correct code. I just changed "private" to "public" and added in `Context ctx;` towards the top. Now I don't have any redlines from eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to chedule the task:

```
ExportDatabaseFileTask thing = new ExportDatabaseFileTask();
thing.execute(.....);
```

Now it will be run from a new tread.

You are trying to access the external storage. Make sure you have necessary permission defined in your Manifest file. This can be done by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) here.

Comment: Wait, so all I have to put is .execute? Or do I need to put something where you put the "...."?

Comment: Wait... from the documentation it says "AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used." What does that mean?

Comment: If you used the code in the provided link, you can pass a String (but i don't see if it is used...) inside the execute. yes your class does extend AsynncTask

Comment: What string do I have to pass? It doesn't look like I need to pass anything.

Comment: My error seems to be "11-13 08:05:33.280: E/dalvikvm(4902): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory" My code is the code from the link in my question. and the code in your answer is in my main activity onClick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19480/discussion-between-eghdk-and-frank)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the code you put in ExportDatabaseFileTask, you can just create an object of that class.

Each time you create an object with .... = new .....(); you are running the constructor; the constructor runs the code that is inside the

```
public ExportDatabaseFileTask()
{
}
```

in this case. Put your code in there, and it will run as soon as you create an ExportDatabaseFileTask object.

Or, in the class ExportDatabaseFileTask, create a method with the code

```
public void exportToSD()
{
//dostuff
}
```

then call thing.exportToSD();