# Duplicate/copy SQL database in data folder

Tags: android, sql, copy

In my app I have to create a new SQL database each time a user does a specific action. Sometimes though I need to change the name of the db file but I don't see how I could do that. So instead I thought of creating a new database with the new name and transfer the old database's data into the new one.
So, to be more clear, I have database A with some data in it. I want to create database B with the same data as A. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814213/making-a-database-backup-to-sdcard-on-android?rq=1): instead of copy your database on SD Card, you can copy it in the same path of the original one and change the name of the new database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the following path

path = "/data/data/<you package name>/databases/<your db>.db";

Get inputstream using above path, And create new file with <another name>.db on the same path.
then create outputstream using <another name>.db
and copy inputstream into outputstream.
```

then delete existing file... may solve your problem.